# Differential Equations book for self-learning

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

After posting this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521706/suggestion-of-around-6-books-in-the-topics-abstract-algebra-linear-algebra), I have decided to separate the contents into multiple questions.

Reasons I am doing this:

- Right tag for each topic, so people who are interested in that topic and watch that tag may suggest rather than one suggests books for all the mentioned topics. So it might be simpler and more efficient.
- Having difficulty to decide as everyone has his own opinion. But I believe there is something common for most of people who have read in this topic.
- I did not get many answers to see common suggestions and take a decision.
- So this post might be as voting post.

---

I need a book in:

$\big( \bigstar \big)$ $\text{Differential Equations}$:

Some suggestions in this website are:

$\star$ "$\text{Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes}$" by "$\text{George F. Simmons}$".

$\star$ "$\text{Ordinary Differential Equations}$" by "$\text{Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Pollard}$".

$\star$ "$\text{Ordinary Differential Equations}$" by "$\text{Vladimir I. Arnold and R. Cooke}$".

$\star$ "$\text{Ordinary Differential Equations}$" by "$\text{Wolfgang Walter and R. Thompson}$".

$\star$ "$\text{Partial Differential Equations}$" by "$\text{Lawrence C. Evan}$".

$\star$ "$\text{Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction}$" by "$\text{Walter A. Strauss}$".

$\star$ "$\text{Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers}$" by "$\text{Stanley J. Farlow}$".

---

Even though I have some knowledge in this topic, I want a book that is easy to read for self-learners, to be as comprehensive as possible (but starting from scratch, so it should not be 2nd text), contains proofs as much as possible, contains good number of examples/exercises, and requires least prerequisites.

---

No one suggested me

---

You can suggest other than the listed above if you think there is a better one, please suggest the best (one book containing ODEs and one book containing PDEs) or (one single book containing both ODEs and PDEs) whichever better (in your opinion).

So if book X contains ODEs and book Y contains PDEs and book Z contains both ODEs and PDEs, I wish you suggest me either (X and Y) or (Z) whichever you think it is the best and satisfies the above criteria.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good 1st PDE book for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/good-1st-pde-book-for-self-study)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757007/best-book-for-differential-equations, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/could-you-recommend-some-classic-textbooks-on-ordinary-partial-differential-equa, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029646/book-recommendation-for-ordinary-differential-equations, etc.